# identify first occurrence of value in a group using DAX in Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have data like below and i want to create a calculated column to get data present in  unique column below using DAX in powerbi.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxT1Q.png)

Comment: Try solution from [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-add-Row-number-over-partition-by-Customer-DAX-or-M-query/m-p/566949). Add row_number and then mark rows with 1 as a "UNIQUE".

Comment: this is not am looking for exactly

Comment: Explain then what are you looking for. As I understand what you've written, you want to find the very first occurrence of each product each day and mark it as a unique. What do you want to do with that information, actually?

Comment: so what am actually looking for is i want to count only 1st occurence of product in a single day, like if same product is present in day1 more than once then i want to consider only one occurence of product. hope am clear

Comment: The solution which you provided is not working here.

Comment: Can you provide any other solution because the one you gave its not working

Comment: Have you tried `DISTINCTCOUNT` in a measure? That what I've said works, but you are probably doing something wrong there